# Restricting Fonts available in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, fonts, eclipse-plugin, birt

I have a customized version of Eclipse, that comes with a customized version of the BIRT plug-in.

I'm looking to restrict the list of fonts made available for selection in the BIRT Report Designer to a specified limited set of Fonts.
Currently the list of Fonts selectable is all Fonts installed on the system.

I've seen the fontConfig.xml file can be edited for the fonts available to the BIRT engine at runtime, but I want to limit the fonts available for selection in the drop-downs of the Eclipse UI

Is there a way to limit this list (just for the BIRT report designer)?

Cheers,
Ro

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't be done - A change/patch to BIRT is required.

org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\designer\util\DEUtil.getSystemFontNames is the point where Fonts are retrieved for the drop-down and that is reading directly from the Eclipse (Display) Environment